# Any good websites that offers free icons or icons to purchase?

Tags: icon

Hi i have the following queries:

1. Are there any websites that offers free icons for mobile design? As in totally free for commercial use and does not need to link back to website?
2. Alternatively, are there any website that offer nice mobile icons for purchase?

Comment: google solve such queries within seconds....

Comment: I use [Fam fam fam icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/).

Comment: @Jack- google doesn't guarantee 'good' results, which is why we ask these questions in the community.

Answer (score 4):

Resource that i always use:

- http://www.iconfinder.com
- http://iconpot.com/